# phonegap event that fires only once per app load?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

i have a multi-page phonegap app

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", yourCallbackFunction, false);
```

is good per page.

But i am asking for the entire app... is there any event that is fired only when the app loads and not the page loads??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far I know there isn't any good way or direct way. If you need it badly you'll require a hack.

After the startup of your app there is a landing page, right!! like `index.html`.

In that page put a `deviceready` event. Do whatever you want to on the app start-up. And then redirect to your main first page say firstpage.html. Don't link back to index.html anymore during app use. Hackish.

Answer (score 0):

Run deviceready only once.

On your other pages use documentready.